# I can't translate the title in navigation menu in my fuse theme Angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, angular-translate

Here is the a part of code in my navigation menu:

```
msNavigationService.saveItem('apps.dashboard', {
        title: 'Dashboard',
        state: 'app.dashboard',
        icon: 'icon-tile-four',
        hidden: function () {
            var dashboardview = true;
            if (localStorage.getItem("DashboardStorage") === '1') { dashboardview = false; }
            else { dashboardview = true; }
            return dashboardview;
        },
        weight: 1

    });
```

I just want to translate the title `Dashboard` with `angular-translate`. All the configuration are okay. 
And here is the way I have done all the translations in controller: 
`var customers = "Dashboard";
        vm.customers = $filter('translate')(customers);`
So the variable in `JSON` named Dashboard will be translated, but the translation couldn't be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
var translations = {
  CUSTOMERS: 'Customers'
};

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', translations);
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
}]);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$translate', function ($scope, $translate) {
   var vm = this;
   vm.customers = $translate.instant('CUSTOMERS');
}]);
```